# How to skip duplicate rows values between separate spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets with different types of data. The only similarity is a list of names spread out across the spreadsheets.

I want to create a script that lets me copy specific rows from **Spreadsheet 2** to **Spreadsheet 1** with two conditions:

1. Only rows marked **Ready** in Spreadsheet 2  should be copied over to Spreadsheet 1
2. No rows containing names already in Spreadsheet 1 should be copied over from Spreadsheet 2

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't get Point 2 to work.

```
    function CopyClick() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var originalnames = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
      
      var otherss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet 2 ID HERE");
      var copysheet = otherss.getSheetByName("Spreadsheet 2 Sheet Name");  
      var copynames = copysheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
      var statusdata = copysheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();  //First condition has to be "Ready"
      
      var copylastrow = copysheet.getLastRow();
      
      
      for(var i=0; i<copylastrow; i++) {
        
        if(statusdata[i][0].toString().match(/Ready/ig) && (copynames[i][0].indexOf(originalnames) === -1)){  //Don't want duplicates, but indexOf isn't working   
          var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
          sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1).setValue(copynames[i][0]); //back to the original spreadsheet
          
        }
      } 
    }
```

As you can see, I wasn't sure of how to keep the second condition, ending up with a placeholder indexOf.

How could I best solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can take advantage of the [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) function. It returns `true` if there is a match. However, you need to [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the `originalnames` array first. I also changed the range of `originalnames` to avoid taking empty cells:

```
var originalnames = sheet.getRange("A1:A"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(1);
```

and inside the if condition use:

```
!originalnames.includes(copynames[i][0])
```

this will evaluate to `true` if `copynames[i][0]` is **not** included in `originalnames` array. I also replaced `statusdata[i][0].toString().match(/Ready/ig)` to `statusdata[i][0] == 'Ready'` but feel free to use your own version if this does not work.

### Solution:

```
  function CopyClick() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var originalnames = sheet.getRange("A1:A"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(1);
      
      var otherss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet 2 ID HERE");
      var copysheet = otherss.getSheetByName("Spreadsheet 2 Sheet Name");  
      var copynames = copysheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
      var statusdata = copysheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();  //First condition has to be "Ready"
      
      var copylastrow = copysheet.getLastRow();
      
      
      for(var i=0; i<copylastrow; i++) {
        
        if( statusdata[i][0] == 'Ready' && !originalnames.includes(copynames[i][0]) ){     
          var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
          sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1).setValue(copynames[i][0]); //back to the original spreadsheet
          
        }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: `flat()` accepts a `number` as argument and not a `array`

Comment: @TheMaster it is whatever you got used to :P They both work the same.

Comment: It works because `array` is coerced to `number`. It'll have unintended side effects later though(if you use a different array).

Comment: I didn't know that.. thanks a lot again :). I also modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the includes() function is just what I'm looking for!  

Edit: However, why did you replace the ``statusdata[i][0].toString().match(/Ready/ig)`` to ``statusdata[i][0] == 'Ready'`` ?  

If I ever wanted multiple search string conditions, such as a Reviewed on top of a Ready, wouldn't it be simpler to keep it as ``statusdata[i][0].toString().match(/Ready|Reviewed/ig)``?